Two almost similar multithreaded code have very different running time
i am having a strange problem for C++ multithreaded programs.
i wrote the first code and was not seeing any performance improvement over single threaded code.
i kept on experimenting with shifting the variables in the functions and the second code took almost half the time of first code.
First code:
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull evenSum = 0;
ull oddSum = 0;
void findEvenSum(ull start, ull end){
    
    for(ull i = start; i<=end; i++){
        if((i&1) == 0){
            evenSum+=i;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Even Sum: "<<evenSum<<"\n";
}

void findOddSum(ull start, ull end){
    
    for(ull i = start; i<=end; i++){
        if((i&1) == 1){
            oddSum+=i;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Odd Sum: "<<oddSum<<"\n";
}
int main(){
    ull start = 0, end = 9999999999;
    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::thread evenSumCalculator(findEvenSum, start, end);
    std::thread oddSumCalculator(findOddSum, start, end);

    evenSumCalculator.join();
    oddSumCalculator.join();

    // findEvenSum(start, end);
    // findOddSum(start, end);

    auto stopTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
    std::cout<<"time taken: "<<duration.count()<<" microseconds\n";

    return 0;
}

Second code:
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull eSum = 0;
ull oSum = 0;

void findEvenSum(ull start, ull end){
    ull evenSum = eSum;
    for(ull i = start; i<=end; i++){
        if((i&1) == 0){
            evenSum+=i;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Even Sum: "<<evenSum<<"\n";
}

void findOddSum(ull start, ull end){
    ull oddSum = oSum;
    for(ull i = start; i<=end; i++){
        if((i&1) == 1){
            oddSum+=i;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Odd Sum: "<<oddSum<<"\n";
}
int main(){
    ull start = 0, end = 9999999999;
    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::thread evenSumCalculator(findEvenSum, start, end);
    std::thread oddSumCalculator(findOddSum, start, end);

    evenSumCalculator.join();
    oddSumCalculator.join();

    // findEvenSum(start, end);
    // findOddSum(start, end);

    auto stopTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
    std::cout<<"time taken: "<<duration.count()<<" microseconds\n";

    return 0;
}

the second program is twice as fast as first program.
i ran the programs without optimizations
What is the reason for this difference in running time?

And how long did both executions take?

"i ran the programs without optimizations"  Why?  You seem to be concerned about the programs' runtimes.  Why tell the compiler that you aren't?

In the 1st test evenSum and oddSum  will probably share the same cache line.  In the 2nd test this is not true as they on separate stacks.  Google for "cache false sharing"

You are also using the wrong clock for timing things.  You should be using std::chrono::steady_clock.

@DrewDormann which clock timing i should use?

Problem is caused by something called "false sharing". Basically problem is that you are using global variables. Those accumulators: evenSum and oddSum are in single cache line and processor have to do some synchronizations.

what are some measures i should take to avoid these issues like false sharing in multithreaded programs?

Generally try to avoid global variables in multi-threaded code - this also simplifies reasoning about thread safety / data-races.  For tasks like the above use a stack local variable and only update the global once at the end of the thread.

I am very tempted to close this as a duplicate of `What is "false sharing"? How to reproduce / avoid it?

"i ran the programs without optimizations" As a general rule, don't do this. In this specific case your results are probably valid, but that's only apparent after the fact, when you know what's causing the difference.

BTW, the 2 programs do different things, as the global don't have same value at the end.

In the first case, you have two variables placed close to each other in the memory. Then, if one thread wants to update, for example, evenSum, it asks from memory cache line with this variable in exclusive access (one of access states of MESI protocol). There's a high chance of oddSum being in this cache line, so second thread loses exclusive access for oddSum, and has to ask it again when it will update it. It's called false sharing, you can read about it here and play with MESI protocol here
